# Windows 7 ODBC Text Driver

Tags: windows-7, drivers, odbc

Some software requires me to setup an ODBC Text Driver.

In the Windows 7 Control Panel > ODBC Data Source Administrator, the only driver available is "SQL Server".

How do I find/download/install a Text driver?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 32 bit drivers are available in Windows 7 64 bit.

navigate here:

C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe

Comment: A recommendation for anyone who needs to access this regularly: Add a shortcut to this version to the Administrative Tools folder.

Answer (score 0):

Same question came up on StackOverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1953416/microsoft-access-text-odbc-driver-on-windows-7).

According to what they found, it looks like the answer is it's been depricated in Windows 7 32-bit (it's been removed, and replaced with more modern alternatives), and all but non-existant for 64-bit versions.

So basically, your software doesn't sound like it's Windows 7 compatible.  You may want to check into using Windows 7's ["XP Mode"](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/download.aspx), or contact the authors for a new version.